# Couldn't load opencv_imgproc from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Tags: android, opencv, webrtc

There is something strange in my code:

when I add the webrtc dependency(compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:11139@aar') in the build.gradle, the error occurs.

build.gradle :

....

compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:11139@aar'

compile project(':openCVLibrary2411')

....

the error info:

Couldn't load opencv_imgproc from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/activitytest.example.com.zhida-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/activitytest.example.com.zhida-1, /vendor/lib, /data/cust/lib, /system/lib, /data/datalib]]]: findLibrary returned null

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done ! The error info means that the project has the conflict 'so' library .

I create a new catalog named "src/main/assets/armeabi",and then take the conflict 'so'

library in it.